# iptables - Forward back to dmz from dmz

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, external-ip

I have a firewall with two network cards. From internet it's possible to access the external-ip and then be forwarded to an internal server. But when on the DMZ and accessing the external-ip, I'm not forwarded back into the internal server.

I guess this is the rules that are relevant to this question. Shouldn't they be enough.

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p TCP -d $MAIL_IP --dport 122 -j DNAT --to-destination $DMZ_MAIL_IP:22

$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p TCP  -o $DMZ_IFACE -d $DMZ_MAIL_IP -m multiport --dports 122 -j allowed
```

I have lot's of other rules, and infact two other network cards, just isolating the question here.

SOLUTION:

I had a to restrictive SNAT rule.

Something like this solved the problem.
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s $INTERNAL_CLIENT -j SNAT --to-source $MAIL_IP